# Blender 2.8 "RenderLayer" button needed

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm missing the "RenderLayer" button from 2.79 that shows the actual render preview as it will look in the final renders. Now the renderpreview does not respect the correct "flags", as objects hidden from render (the camera icon toggle) still shows up in the preview. Is this an oversight or can I somehow preview how the actual render will look like without toggling and retoggling all my collections or the objects within them?
[image]

Comment: They layer system was rewritten for 2.8  Instead of layers there is now a collections system.  I don't understand it myself yet, so I recommend looking for some tutorials on the difference between layers and collections.

Comment: Yes, I have the grasp of collections, I like them alot! The problem is that I can't preview exactly what will be shown/hidden in the final render - without having manually hide every object/collection from the viewport. I read somewhere that they decided the RenderLayer-button won't be needed since the preview should always show what will be rendered, but this is simply not the case yet.